# Gunicorn + flask + nginx + wsgi error 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ubuntu, python, nginx

I have tried looking for an answer, but mostly people get this error with `uwsgi` not `Gunicorn`.

`nginx` error log has the following output:

```
2019/09/20 17:23:20 [crit] 28847#28847: *2 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/app_test/app_test.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: <client-ip>, server: <server-ip>, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/app_test/app_test.sock:/", host: "<ip-address>"
```

I have the following configuration file for the app in `nginx`'s `sites-available` directory with a simlink to in `sites-enabled`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <server-ip>;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/app_test/app_test.sock;
    }
}
```

This is the service file in `/etc/systemd/system/app_test.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve app_test
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/app_test
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/app_test/appenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/app_test/appenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app_test.sock -m 002 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(By the way, I have tried the socket file with a mask of `007` as well, just to be sure. Still the same response in the log after restarting both service and `nginx`.)

This is the `app_test.py`file:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Finally, this is `wsgi.py`:

```
from app_test import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error was within the Gunicorn service file. 
Since `nginx` was configured to run in the `www-data` group, it didn't have access to the `app_test.sock` file. I changed the group setting to `www-data` and it's working great now!